# maven surefire plugin include/exclude

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I don't know what is going on, but  with a bunch of  tags each containing a package name actually excludes the package from maven test phase. While exclude includes those packages during test phase.

I have simple surefire config.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>...</include>
                    ...     
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But surefire documentation says the exact opposite is true.
https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

What am I missing something ?

Comment: Best is to have no configuration at all...put your test classes into `src/test/java` and name them like `*Test.java` for unit tests...everything else should work out of the box...no include/exlcudes needed...

Comment: True, but I have a wierd project that has hundreds of tests. My instructions are to leave them in place but ignore them and start writing new unit tests. I know it doesn't make sense. But that is what I have to work with. So I have to exclude some 15 packages. It works now, only I have to use `include` instead of `exclude`.

Comment: Simply wrong way...but I can't change it....so it's up to you...

Comment: [mcve]! What **exactly** are you trying to include/exclude? `...` is not a valid filename.